# Is this operation on sets at all useful?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

As I’ve been learning more about Logic and Mathematical Logic in particular, I’ve had to learn more about sets. I was one of those people who I would get members of members of sets mixed up with members of sets, and so on.

I was browsing MathOverflow and came across some questions on Mereology, and learned that it is quite similar to Set Theory. I decided to try to find what my intuition had been using the language of sets. I’m assuming a theory at least as strong as $\sf ZF$.

Define $f(z)=\{x|x=y \lor x \in f(y)\}$ for any set $z$ and some $y \in z$. For example,

- $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$
- $f(\{\emptyset,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$
- $f(\{\{\emptyset\}\})=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Define $a\triangleleft b:=a \in f(b)$, which I pronounce as “$a$ constitutes $b$.”

My question is two-fold: is this operation already defined, and can it be used for something like defining existing operators such as $\in,\subset$ and so on?

I do know that this operation resembles the way that a well-formed formula is constructed according to some canonical formation rules. That is, $f(b)$ bears a resemblance to a sequence of wffs used in the construction of another wff, e.g.

- $\langle p,q,(q \to p), (p \to (q \to p))\rangle$

Comment: You have defined f(z) using f(y) which usually implies some kind of recursive process, what is your base case?

Comment: Since $\emptyset$ has no members, no members satisfy the condition to be in $f(\emptyset)$, so the base case is the empty set.

Comment: I think the "*and all $y\in z$.*" should be "for some". As in $f(z) = \{x\mid \exists y\in z, (x=y\lor x=f(y))\}$?

Comment: @PW_246 that holds if the chosen set z contains the empty set.  But what if it doesn't ?

Comment: @MichaelCarey That’s fine since the null set is still a member of…a member of the first set.

Comment: @PW_246 It looks to me like you are trying to define a process which returns the "elements of elements of elements... etc.." of a set. If so, this is a known operation, called the transitive closure of x.

Comment: @peterwhy I see, thanks for catching that. I’ll edit it.

Comment: @peterwhy I do apologize, but I wrote this just after work. The second disjunct is supposed to say $x \in f(y)$.